# Could a magnetron wavelength theoretically get short enough to pass between quarks in a nucleus?

Tags: atomic-physics

Would it be possible to set a magnetron wavelength to / or fabricate a device that could produce a wavelength smaller than a quark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Image Source: [Wikipedia Electromagnetic Spectrum](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_spectrum#/media/File%3AEM_Spectrum_Properties_edit.svg)

I am hoping in this answer, that a picture is worth a thousand words.

Comment: The EM spectrum isn't what I don't understand, the capabilities of a magnetron is what I was asking.

Comment: Well, if a magnetron could be tweaked to produce that level of  high energy, high frequency radiation, then why build the LHC?

Comment: Because we want to observe the properties of atoms when they are accelerated to near the speed of light, including how fast they decay during ionization, when they collide, nuclear decay and other experiments?

Comment: Yeah, ( in general) we need an enormous  amount of energy to "see" details and investigate properties at small scales, in the same way as we need a lot more energy to use an electron microscope, compared to a light microscope. A magnetron could not handle that level of energy.

Comment: Due to the current composition? What properties are lacking in the current materials? Conductiveness? Melting point? Hardness? We could not fabricate the chambers with the right dimensions for the emissions? etc.

Comment: No, a magnetron is designed for microwaves,  and that's it. It's like putting a family car into a Formula 1 race, you have no chance of winning.  If you want to investigate properties or particles that only emerge at high energies, you can only get those energies by banging particles together at almost the maximum speed that is physically possible.  You need the  [Large Hadron Collider](http://home.cern/topics/large-hadron-collider)

Comment: I understand that the current magnetrons are not designed for high powered outputs and Lasers have been investigated as a result of this, however I was wondering if the limitations were based on the wire thickness for the waveguide, the amount of conductivity within the electrodes/cathodes/anodes etc, the fabricatable dimensions of the cavity, the ability to resonate the wave of that power without it escaping from the cavity between the atomic structure etc.

If I phrased it another way, I would ask if any devices could, such as the Laser for Fast Ignition Experiments (LFEX).

Comment: This magnetron seems to output gigawatt levels on the xray spectrum, so theoretically I am still thinking it is due to limitations on components: http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a090410.pdf

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible, because there is no "between" quarks in a nucleon (that is, the particles that make up the nucleus). Quarks are fundamentally quantum-mechanical objects whose wavefunctions always overlap.

If by "magnetron" you have in mind a radio or microwave source, there's the additional complication that the size of a nucleon is only about one femtometer.  The energy of a one-femtometer photon is
$$
E = h\nu = \frac{hc}{\lambda} = \frac{\rm1240\,MeV\,fm}{\rm1\,fm} \approx \rm1\,GeV
$$
but radio and microwave photons are in the milli- and micro-eV energy ranges.

In a comment, you propose reducing the wavelength by printing some sort of angstrom-scale magnetron antenna.  Still doesn't help you: an angstrom-scale antenna would resonate at angstrom-scale wavelengths.  Atoms are just too big. If you want to look inside of a nucleus, you have to do nuclear physics. (Exceptions to this rule of thumb are actually my research area --- but the tricks we use are very different from your proposal here, and I'm not able to elaborate further right now.)